# How to remove 'Bearer' prefix in Swagger laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt, swagger, bearer-token

My JWT token requires `Bearer` prefix every time I enter the token in swagger.

So how can I remove this `Bearer` prefix usage in Laravel? If I do not prefix it, the authorization fails.

I have tried to add this piece of code in my `controller.php` file but nothing happened:

```php
@OA\SecurityScheme(
    type="http",
    securityScheme="bearerAuth",
    scheme="bearer",
    bearerFormat="JWT"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the error in this and resolved it.

In my l5-swagger.php file i just commented this part of code and now the tokens are working without using Bearer Prefix :

```
'bearerAuth' => [
     'type' => 'apiKey',
     'description' => 'Enter token in format (Bearer <token>)',
     'name' => 'Authorization',
     'in' => 'header',
]
```